# How to connect mysql database in groovy using connection parameters from command line?

Tags: mysql, groovy

I need to connect my MySQL database from Groovy script.
Since the intend of this script is to use for db update with minor change in it; I need to able to supply  the necessary connection parameters with jar file. I would like to input connection parameters such as dbUrl, dbUsername, and dbPassword dynamically so that I can input those as per database. Below code successfully connect to database, but it is manual. I have to create jar file for each database if I have to use for other database than 'test'.

I am relatively new to groovy, any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

How do I proceed with this?

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql
 import java.sql.*
 import java.io.File

  Sql sql
  def cities = []
 try{
    def url= 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'
    def username = 'username'
    def password = 'password'
    def driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
    sql = Sql.newInstance( url, username, password, driver)
    sql.eachRow("select * from City where city are not null"){cities += it.city}
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the script below with:

```
groovy dbscript jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test username password
```

dbscript.groovy

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql
 import java.sql.*
 import java.io.File

if ( args.size() != 3 ) {
    println 'Please supply DB URL, username and password'
    System.exit(0)
}

 Sql sql
 def cities = []
 try{
    def url= args[0]
    def username = args[1]
    def password = args[2]
    def driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
    sql = Sql.newInstance( url, username, password, driver)
    sql.eachRow("select * from City where city are not null"){cities += it.city}
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike W.

Comment: @Sam, if the answer is helpful, you need to consider accepting it as answer.

Comment: @Rao, I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: You mean the answer isn't helpful?